# Unable to move Elasticsearch shards

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have an Elasticsearch cluster with two nodes and eight shards. I am in the situation where all primaries are on one node and all replicas are on the other.

Running the command:

```
http://xx.xx.xx.1:9200/_cat/shards
```

returns this result:

```
myindex              2 r STARTED 16584778   1.4gb xx.xx.xx.2 node2
myindex              2 p STARTED 16584778   1.4gb xx.xx.xx.1 node1
myindex              1 r STARTED 16592755   1.4gb xx.xx.xx.2 node2
myindex              1 p STARTED 16592755   1.4gb xx.xx.xx.1 node1
myindex              3 r STARTED 16592009   1.4gb xx.xx.xx.2 node2
myindex              3 p STARTED 16592033   1.4gb xx.xx.xx.1 node1
myindex              0 r STARTED 16610776   1.3gb xx.xx.xx.2 node2
myindex              0 p STARTED 16610776   1.3gb xx.xx.xx.1 node1
```

I am trying to swap around certain shards by posting this command:

```
http://xx.xx.xx.1:9200/_cluster/reroute?explain
```

with this body:

```
{
    "commands" : [
        {
            "move" : {
                "index" : "myindex",
                "shard" : 1,
                "from_node" : "node1",
                "to_node" : "node2"
            }
        },
        {
            "allocate_replica" : {
                "index" : "myindex",
                "shard" : 1,
                "node" : "node1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It doesn't work, and the only "NO" I get in the list of decisions in the explainitions is:

```
{
    "decider": "same_shard",
    "decision": "NO",
    "explanation": "the shard cannot be allocated on the same node id [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] on which it already exists"
},
```

It's not fully clear to me if this is the actual error, but there is no other negative feedback. How can I resolve this and move my shard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected.
Why would you do that? Primaries and replicas are doing the same job.

What problems do you think this would solve?

Comment: Most guidance for Elasticsearch I read suggests that it is preferable to spread the primary shards across the available nodes? I this not the case?

Comment: If it was the case elasticsearch would do that automatically as soon as replicas are allocated. Where did you read that?

Comment: So it's perfectly valid to have all my primaries on one node and all my replicas on the other?

Comment: Yes. I don’t think it’s bad.

Comment: But note that it’s better to have 3 nodes to avoid split brain issues.

Comment: Diagrams like the ones here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/replica-shards.html made me think otherwise, but the note at the end does say "There is no need to ensure that primaries are distributed evenly across all nodes." May look into 3 nodes.